# Writing to sdcard using native JRE methods on Android 5.0+

Tags: android, io, android-permissions

I have a library that works with files using RandomAccessFile class. Trying to run it results in throwing exception that says "(EACCESS): Permission denied". How can I get this permission using new sdcard access API?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in your android manifest

Comment: The question is about Android 5.0+, where Manifest permission doesn't work